# Cannot acces to this in Class method

Tags: node.js, typescript, express

I am writing an API REST in Typescript using express.

I want to declare only once connection informations about database. Beacause actualy my code is runing correctly but I redefine for each route the connection informations. 
I tried to define these informations in the constructor but at runtime, I have the following error message : `TypeError: Cannot read property 'connAttrs' of undefined`

This is my code :

```
    import {Router, Request, Response, NextFunction} from 'express';
    import * as path from 'path';
    import * as oracledb from "oracledb";

    export class FormFieldsRouterOracle {
        router: Router;
        connAttrs;

        /**
         * Initialize the FormFieldsRouterOracle
         */
        constructor() {
            this.connAttrs = {
                    'user': 'test',
                    'password': 'test',
                    'connectString': 'linkToDatabase'
                };
            this.router = Router();
            this.init();
        }

        /**
         * GET all fields.
         */
        public getAll(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) {
            // const conn = {
            //         'user': 'test',
            //         'password': 'test',
            //         'connectString': 'linkToDatabase'
            // };
            // Using conn instead of this.connAttrs works fine

            oracledb.getConnection(this.connAttrs, (err, connection) => {
                if (err) {
                    return console.error(err.message);
                }

                const sql = 'SELECT * FROM my_table';
                connection.execute(sql, {}, {outFormat: oracledb.OBJECT}, (err, result) => {
                    if (err) {
                        console.error(err.message);
                    }
                    else {
                        res.send(JSON.stringify(result.rows));
                    }

                    connection.release(err => {
                        if (err) {
                            console.error(err.message);
                        }
                        else {
                            console.log("getAll : Connectioon released");
                        }
                    })
                });
            });

        }
        /**
         * Take each handler, and attach to one of the Express.Router's
         * endpoints.
         */
        init() {
            this.router.get('/', this.getAll);
        }
    }

    // Create the FormFieldsRouter, and export its configured Express.Router
    const formFieldsRoutes = new FormFieldsRouterOracle();
    formFieldsRoutes.init();

    export default formFieldsRoutes.router;
```

I guess it is probably relatated to the reach of `this` but I tried several things without success. I also want to avoid arrow function and continue to use `this.getAll` in my `init()` method.

Comment: This is being asked twice per day. replace `this.getAll` by `(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => this.getAll(req, res next)`, or by `this.getAll.bind(this)`

Comment: thanks for you answer !